# Should I use mysql or ssdb to store like/vote data?

Tags: mysql, redis, social-networking, sharding, nosql

Every user can vote for any videos, currently we're using mysql, but now we have over 200 million lines in a single table with fields like this:

```
id
user_id     # the voter
video_id    # voted video
author_id   # author of the video
state       # 1 for normal and 0 for cancelled, maybe others
created_at
```

The most common query is get voters of specific video, but maybe voters of videos by certain author, or videos voted by certain user are also needed, usually ordered by time.

Should I shard the table into 100 shards (by video_id) or use ssdb instead?

If I choose the former, in order to query by author_id or user_id, the data have to be stored several times.

If I choose ssdb, I think I should use ordered set and store the timestamp as score to sort, and have several keys for each user or video in order to query by different fields and handle different states. And it's difficult to change the code and migrate the data.

Comment: 100 shards -- you are willing top buy 100 servers?  ("Sharding" implies separate servers.)

Answer (score 1):

Had same confusion.
What I do is using both of them together:

- Redis for caching hot data;
- MySQL for data persistent;

No doubt more Redis keys come with more complexity, however there must be a caching module for reducing queries to MySQL.

And because I just use Redis as a cache, the data in it can be threw away at any time: I can set up new data structures in Redis with data from MySQL。

And I personally don't want to put all data only in Redis: the memory is much more expensive than hard disk on IAAS.

Wish this helps :)

Comment: Redis on top of MySQL is best solution - you keep in Redis data used most often.

Answer (score 0):

If you go with MySQL, you need some advice on the details...

```
CREATE TABLE Votes (
    # id -- no need for this
    user_id   INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,     # the voter
    video_id  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,    # voted video
    author_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   # author of the video
    state TINYINT UNSIGNED (or ENUM) NOT NULL, # 1 for normal and 0 for cancelled, maybe others
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(video_id, user_id),  -- see note
    + some indexes; see below
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

It is unclear what will *uniquely* identify a record.  I guessed at something, but I am assuming a user can vote only once.

`INT UNSIGNED` assumes you won't have more than 4 billion ids.  It takes 4 bytes, as opposed to `BIGINT` at 8 bytes.  If you won't need more than 16M ids for a particular thing, use `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (only 3 bytes).

"The most common query is get voters of specific video."  (Not "number of votes"?)

```
SELECT user_id FROM Votes WHERE video_id = ?;
# INDEX(video_id, user_id) -- not needed, assuming the PK specified above.
-- or
SELECT user_id FROM Votes WHERE video_id = ? ORDER BY created_at;
INDEX(video_id, created_at, user_id)
```

"but maybe voters of videos by certain author" (Seems like `video_id` is irrelevant here):

```
SELECT user_id FROM Votes WHERE author_id = ?;
INDEX(author_id, user_id)
-- or
SELECT user_id FROM Votes WHERE author_id = ? ORDER BY created_at;
INDEX(author_id, created_at, user_id)
```

"or videos voted by certain user are also needed, usually ordered by time."

```
SELECT video_id FROM Votes WHERE user_id = ? ORDER BY created_at;
INDEX(user_id, created_at, video_id)
```

With those suggestions, the queries will be quite fast.  Furthermore, MySQL will do it's own caching, so adding another caching layer probably won't help (especially if it robs RAM).

The table will take several GB.